# address book data

Tags: iphone, string, addressbook, bold

To create my own address book i have copy all contacts from address book and stored them in an array but i need to **bold** the last name in the array, for eg if array have object "abc efg" then i need to **bold** only efg in the array how can i do it please help any one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not Bold it in the array.
you should make it bold when you write it to the TableViewCell or any other view you write it to.
can you paste the code you use to write the name?

Comment: i agree with you completely @shani

Comment: ok i agree and keep it in mind , my code is  cell.textLabel.text = [_listContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  and each of its object i have complete name so how to **bold**